# ¿Cómo llenar un DataGridView desde un Subproceso?

Tags: c#

Estoy corriendo mi método en un subproceso. En dicho método inserto datos a un `DataGridView`. El problema que a la hora de llegar a esa tarea me tira un error que no se puede ejecutar el proceso en el mismo plano creado.

Entonces alguien me puede ayudar o darme algún material para poder insertar datos en mi dgv en un subproceso

Comment: Aunque es posible, yo no haría eso. Lo normal es que almacenes los datos en tu proceso que corre en otro hilo en alguna estructura (`DataTable`, `List<T>`)... y que una vez se complete el proceso, pases esa estructura de datos al `DataGridView`

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Lo probare!

Comment: Debes hacerlo a través de la referencia del subproceso o hilo de la UI, utilizando el dispatcher.Invoke()